# What is the connection of Gell-Mann matrices with SU(3)?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

Are Gell-Mann matrices the *generators* of SU(3)?
Are Gell-Mann matrices the *representation* of SU(3)?

What are the generators of SU(3)?
What is the representation of SU(3)?
is there one or several representations of SU(3)?

What is the connection of Gell-Mann matrices with SU(3)?

Comment: "They span the Lie algebra of the SU(3)" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices). This means that they are generators for (at least a neighborhood of unit) $SU(3).$ Note: $SU(3)$ is the [Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group). The [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) is denoted $\mathfrak{su}(3),$ although it's common that physicists also write $SU(3)$ for the algebra.

Comment: @md2perpe thank you for your help. "They span the Lie algebra of the SU(3)" is not really precise enough. It is not a mathematical sentence as "they are ...". You give very useful information. So you mean that the Gell-Mann *are* the generators. But in this web page, they say that "The matrices can be realized as a representation of the infinitesimal generators of the special unitary group called SU(3)", which is not very precise is they would mean that "there are the representation". And also, you mean that a Lie group is different to a Lie algebra ?!? That is very complex...

Comment: A Lie group $G$ is a group that is also a smooth manifold with the group operations being smooth. The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ associated to $G$ is the tangent space at unit of $G$. It's a vector space having an anticommutative operation $[\bullet, \bullet] : \mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}.$

Comment: @md2perpe : Thank you. Would you know what is the *representation* of SU(3) ?

Comment: $SU(3)$ is a Lie group consisting of $3 \times 3$-matrices. Its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gu}(3)$ also consists of $3 \times 3$-matrices. The Gell-Mann matrices constitute a basis of $\mathfrak{gu}(3)$ and are generators of $SU(3).$

Comment: by the way, is generators *synonym* to basis ?

Comment: It seems like all elements in the Lie algebra are called a (infinitesimal) generators, not only those in some chosen basis of the Lie algebra. But it's common, at least in physics, to just mean the elements in some chosen basis.

Comment: @md2perpe : thank you. You have already helped me a lot with your informations.

Comment: A [representation of a Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_of_a_Lie_group) $G$ is any smooth group homomorphism $\phi : G \to GL(V)$ for some vector space $V$. Usually one works with injective representations (called *faithful*).

Comment: @md2perpe : but people often say that the representation of SU(3) is "3". is it true ? *What* is "3" ? (what is his content ?). 3 seems to be just a "coded name".

Comment: @md2perpe : According to : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#Fundamental_representation the Gell-Mann matrices are not the *basis* of $\mathfrak{su(3)}$ but the (almost) the *generators* of $\mathfrak{su(3)}$. More precisely, they say that the generators are *half* times the Gell-Mann matrices. So I'm lost...

Comment: I cannot see that they say that the Gell-Mann matrices do not constitute a basis of $\mathfrak{su}(3).$ And the factor $\frac12$ doesn't matter much. If $\{ e_1, \ldots, e_n \}$ is a basis for an $n$-dimensional linear space then so is $\{ \frac12 e_1, \ldots, \frac12 e_n \}.$

Comment: let's forget the factor 1/2 : apparently this is a choice of physicists. My point is that they don't say that Gell-Mann matrices are a *basis* of $\mathfrak{su(3)}$ : they say that they are *generator* : "The generators T of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su(3)}$"

Comment: The Gell-Mann matrices *both* constitute a basis of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ *and* are generators of $SU(3).$

Comment: Sure I have understood but they write that there are the generator of the *algebra*. Just read the sentence of my link

Comment: I'm not a Lie group/algebra expert, but it seems like both "generators of the Lie group" and "generators of the Lie algebra" are used for the same elements.

Comment: All right. Thank you for your help

Comment: If you want to learn some about Lie groups and Lie algebras (and other mathematics used in physics) I can recommend the lessons by Frederic Schuller on Youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJ8ZDdA10GY

Comment: ah very good thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Are Gell-Mann matrices the *generators* of SU(3)"?

Yes they are!

> "Are Gell-Mann matrices the *representation* of SU(3)?"

There's more than one "representation", as explained [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/102657/134583). I'll list some of them here:

- Fundamental representation
- Adjoint representation
- Defining representation
- Spin representation
- Trivial representation

> "What are the generators of SU(3)?"

A subset of SU(3) such that every element of SU(3) can be expressed as a combination of a finite number of elements of the subset and their inverses. The Gell-Mann matrices are just ***one example*** of generators of SU(3).

What is the representation of SU(3)?

They are generators of the SU(3) group in the ***defining representation***.

> "is there one or several representations of SU(3)?"

There's several, as mentioned above.

> "What is the connection of Gell-Mann matrices with SU(3)"?

They are ***generators*** of the SU(3) group in the ***defining representation***.